# Knockout.js boolean select list options

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a dropdown list which binding using Knockout. The dropdown list only has two options, however, I require the values for the options to be true and false.

View

```
@model WebApplication13.Models.IndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<select data-bind="options: userOptions, value: userStatus, event: { change: selectionChanged }"></select>

@section Script {
    <script src="~/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>

        var options = {
            userStatus: @(Model.IsNewUser ? "true" : "false"),
        };

        var viewModel = init(options);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    </script>
}
```

Javascript

```
function init(options) {

    var viewModel = {
        userStatus: ko.observable(options.userStatus),
        userOptions: ko.observableArray(['New User', 'Old User'])
    };

    viewModel.selectionChanged = function(event) {
        alert(viewModel.userStatus());
    } 

    return viewModel;
};
```

However, when I select either 'New User' or 'Old User', the value of '`userStatus`' is 'New User' or 'Old User', rather than true or false. Not sure what i'm doing wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That's because your `userOptions` is indeed only contains strings instead of a key-value pair object that is containing both the value (`boolean`) and the caption (`string`).

Try this:

```
userOptions: ko.observableArray([
      { value: true, caption: 'New User' },
      { value: false, caption: 'Old User' }
])
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: userOptions,
                   optionsValue: 'value',
                   optionsText: 'caption',
                   value: userStatus,
                   event: { change: selectionChanged }">
```

See [Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0053oja/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [optionsText](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) binding to determine what the text shown in `<select>` should be.

```
<select data-bind="options: userOptions, optionsText: textForOption, value: userStatus, event: { change: selectionChanged }"></select>

var viewModel = {
        userStatus: ko.observable(options.userStatus),
        userOptions: ko.observableArray(['true', 'false']),
        textForOption: function (option) {
            if (option === 'true') {
                return 'New User';
            } else {
                return 'Old User';
            }
        },
    };
```